# How to integrate weibo login on my website?

Tags: php, authentication, social-networking, weibo

I have a login with facebook feature on our website. Does chinese social network weibo have such a feature?

Where can I read about weibo API or login integration?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about Weibo or their API. But you might start checking their API reference: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3/en

Comment: Thank you! Was unable to find that by self.

Comment: No problem! I'll just post this as an answer in case someone else stumbles upon it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking their API reference should help: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3/en